Optimizing olive oil production using linear programming
This is a challenge problem from my course on linear programming, the translation was done from french to english using ChatGPT, and edited by me a little bit. Sorry if certain things are imprecise.
The Problem:
A company produces three different qualities of olive oil. The maximum quantities that can be sold each month, as well as the selling prices, are given in the table below:



Product
Maximum Sales (liters)
Selling Price (€/liter)




Oil A
3000
4


Oil B
3000
6


Oil C
2000
10



The company pays €1000 per ton of olives. Each ton of olives yields either 300 liters of oil A or 200 liters of oil B (the costs of these transformations are not modeled). Each liter of oil A can be refined to produce 6 deciliters of oil B and 3 deciliters of oil C. The cost of such refining is €0.50 per liter. Similarly, each liter of oil B can be refined to produce 8 deciliters of oil C. The cost of this refining is €0.30 per liter.
Question 1 – Formulate a linear programming model to help the company determine a monthly production plan that maximizes its profit. Clearly specify the decision variables, the objective function, and the constraints.
My attempt:
If I ignore the refining process and oil C, I arrive at the following simplified solution:
Maximize:$$
4A + 6B - \left(\frac{1000}{300} A + \frac{1000}{200} B\right)
$$
And the constraints are :
$ A \leq 3000 $
$ B \leq 3000 $
$A, B >= 0 $
I reasoned as follows. We want to maximize profit, so we add the selling prices of each type of oil (A, B, but not C because I don't know how to handle it). Then, we subtract the cost of olives required to produce each type of oil (calculated based on the amount that can be produced of oil A and B from one ton of olives).
However, when I factor in the refining process and the production of oil C, the problem becomes much more complicated. I’m struggling to figure out how to properly model the transformation of oils A and B into oil C, and how to have correct constraints and objective function.

Your problem with the refining process can be fixed by introducing additional variables.
First we have the variables for the amount of the oil types in liters (after refining): $y_a, y_b, y_c$
Then let $x_{ab}$ the amount of oil $A$ that is refined to oil $B$ and $x_a$ the amount of oil A which will be not refined. Similar notation for the other variables. Then we have the following equation for the amount of oil types $A, B$ and $C$:
$y_a=x_a$, $y_b=x_b+x_{ab}, y_c=x_c+x_{ac}+x_{bc}$
Then, for instance, we have the following conditions:
Each liter of oil A can be refined to produce 6 deciliters of oil B and 3 deciliters of oil C.
This leads to the two equations $0.6x_a=x_{ab}$ and $0.3x_a=x_{ac}$
For the maximum constraint of oil type A we have: $x_a+x_{ab}+x_{ac}\leq 3000$. Here $x_a+x_{ab}+x_{ac}$ is the amount of oil type $A$ before refining.
And the profit function is
$4x_a+6x_b+10x_c-(x_a+x_b+x_{ab}+x_c+x_{ac}+x_{bc})-0.5x_{ac}-0.5x_{ab}-0.3x_{bc}$
$4x_a+6x_b+10x_c$: Revenue of sold oil
$x_a+x_b+x_{ab}+x_c+x_{ac}+x_{bc}:$ Cost of the purchased oil. One Euro per liter of each type.
$0.5x_{ac}+0.5x_{ab}+0.3x_{bc}$: Transformation cost.

Of course, that makes perfect sense thank you!

I am not sure I understand this $x_a + x_b + x_{ab} + x_c + x_{ac} + x_{bc}$: Cost of the purchased oil. One Euro per liter of each type This is the total amount of oil produced, not purchased. Shouldn't the cost of purchased oil be $\frac{1000}{300} A + \frac{1000}{200} B$ (amount of oil $A$ produced, the refined and unrefined one, and $B$ produced, the refined and unrefined one)? So the equation is this $\frac{1000}{300} (x_a + x_{ab} + x_{ac}) + \frac{1000}{200} (x_b + x_{bc})$
